# Method to find the name of state with more members

Tags: java, arrays

I have a main method that reads the contents of a text file and adds those contents to an `ArrayList` of `Membership` (an object I created). Each `Membership` object has a state of origin. I need a way to count the number of members from each individual state and compare them. Any ideas?

```
public class Membership {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Membership Information ID=" + ID + ", Name=" + name + ", Phone=" + phone + ", State=" + state + ", Email=" + email
                + ", Company=" + company;
    }
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String state;
    private String email;
    private String company;
    private String DOB;
    private String MemDate;
    private String age;


    public Membership(String iD, String name, String phone, String state,String company, String DOB,String MemDate, String email) {
        super();
        ID = iD;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.MemDate = MemDate;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.state = state;
        this.email = email;
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        String shortDate = DOB.substring(DOB.length() - 4);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(shortDate);
        return 2016 - b;
    }
    public void setDOB(String dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }
    public String getMemDate() {
        return MemDate;
    }
    public void setMemDate(String memDate) {
        MemDate = memDate;
    }
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }


}
```

Comment: And where is your code ?

Comment: Start by posting the code for `Membership` and what you tried.

Comment: Please share with us the code you attempted for a better understanding

Comment: Share your code to make it more clear

Comment: added membership class code. It's read from a text file and the text file uses the acronyms for the states. An example would be "IL" for Illinois.

Comment: It is meaningless without knowing how you are storing the data, and how data is supposed to be processed in your program.  Solutions can be things like: Import the data to DB and run a SQL; Make use of JPA and run a JPQL; In Unix, use `grep` to find out matching lines in your text file; etc

Comment: and, before you go any further, first thing you need to learn is the naming convention of Java, and learn to use proper data types

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with stream operations :

```
allMemberships.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Membership::getState, Collectors.counting()))
```

This will return a `Map<State, Count>`, given `allMemberships` is a `Collection<Membership>`.

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/rLIBuP).

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Hint: you can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to accumulate the number of people in each state.